# In CQ5, how do I configure an extJS component?

Tags: extjs, aem

This question is specific to Adobe CQ5, so ExtJS answers by themselves won't be that helpful.

I have a custom text component with a menu option to change the background color. We're referencing a colorfield component in our dialog.xml, and so far everything works. The color menu appears with the default set of colors in the palette and can be clicked. So far so good.

I would now like to customize the palette and only show a select set of colors specific to our client. How do I achieve this?

Here's the relevant dialog.xml snippet so far:

```
<bgcolor
jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
fieldLabel="Background color"
name="./bgColor"
showHexValue="true"
xtype="colorfield"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on dev.day.com - http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5/Development/HowToCreateCustomClientLib.html

Simply put, override the ExtJS widget with your own. Not ideal but it'll do.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you could probably get by creating a custom ColorField to call a custom ColorMenu which sets a custom ColorPalette. If ColorField had configurable options, these would probably be mentioned in the Ext docs or found in the JS file itself in /libs/cq/ui/widgets/..

Comment: +1 This is the answer that you want to go for, as it has the least customisation. The colorfield has a `color` (`String[]`) property that will take a list of hex codes to use, or it can take a ColorPalette (http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.ColorField)